# Hide uib-tooltip after a delay while using tooltip-is-open

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4, tooltip

I have a tooltip on a save button, when the button is disabled (e.g. invalid data is entered), I want to show a tooltip and then after some delay make it disappear. I use 
`tooltip-is-open` to open the tooltip, but then I dont know how to close it. I tried
`tooltip-popup-close-delay` but that needs a close trigger.

Here is a simple version of the code:

```
<button ng-disabled="$ctrl.isInvalid">
<span
    class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"
    uib-tooltip="Some message"
    tooltip-enable="$ctrl.isInvalid"
    tooltip-is-open="$ctrl.isInvalid"></span>
Save
</button>
```

Comment: this is what you are looking for: https://plnkr.co/edit/9zWieWIRqlkRuuJoEmTa?p=preview&preview

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler way without having to create a directive, but this is very helpful thank you.